# How can I obfuscate my Typescript + react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, obfuscation

please tell me how can I obfuscate my Typescript + React app.
P.S i created the project via create-react-app --template typescript

Comment: Is it a big project? Or does it have only few small components?

Comment: @Sowam I would not say that this is a big project and also I would not say that it is small

Comment: There are many options; I'd start by searching the web (that it's TS doesn't matter since TS compiles down to JS).

Comment: @DaveNewton the problem is that it is still react, that is, the tsx extension

Comment: If I would have a project where I can obfuscate it manually by copy pasting code in online obfuscators I would go for it. I will also obfuscate only files that I don't want anyone to see

Comment: @Sowam again, the issue is that is not vanilla js it's tsx

Comment: JSX/TSX is transpiled to JS; browsers don't speak JSX.

Comment: @Sowam I tried to find online typescript and react obfuscator, i didn't find find

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah I know, so when I do npm run build and I should go to build folder then obfuscate generated file?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using JSDefender for almost a year now. It has helped me obfuscate react, angular and javascript project. You can try the trial period to see if it is adapted for your project as well.